# jquery-mobile - why plugin doesn't fire if trigger page is pulled in externally?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-mobile

I need some help:

- I have three separate JQM pages - page1.html, page2.html and page3.html.
- I'm adding my .js files to all pages, so whichever page is loaded first also loads the plugin
- page2.html has a trigger called *data-somesome="true"* to fire the plugin on page2
- I have added a listener that waits for the *trigger* page to be created

Looks like this:

```
(function($,window){
   $.widget("mobile.somesome",$.mobile.widget, {
      _create: function() { 
          var self = this;
          console.log("here we go");
          ...
          }
   });
   // initialize
   var trigger = $('div:jqmData(somesome="true")').live( 'pagecreate',function(event){ 
   if ($('html').data('somesome-init', 'Off')) {
        $('html').data('somesome-init', 'On')
        console.log("trigger fired");
        trigger.somesome();
        }
    });
}) (jQuery,this);
```

**Problem:**
If I load page2.html directly, everything works as normal = console logs the trigger has been fired and the plugin runs.

However, if I start on either page1.html or page3.html and then call page2.html hoping the plugin would fire, I only get the console "trigger fired", so I'm detecting correct, but the plugin itself doesn't run.

Can anybody give me a hint?

**EDIT** 
Added some examples:
- page2 direct [load this directly, and the color changes to red](http://www.franckreich.de/jqm/page2.html)
- via page1 [start from here, then go to page2, nothing happens](http://www.franckreich.de/jqm/page1.html)
- via page3 [or start from here and go to page2, also nothing happens](http://www.franckreich.de/jqm/page3.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**$(this)** makes it work... like so:

```
var trigger = $('div:jqmData(somesome="true")').live( 'pagecreate',function(event){ 
    if ($('html').data('some-init', 'Off')) {
        $('html').data('some-init', 'On')
            $( this ).somesome();
            }
     });
```